# GDI CreatePolyPolygon and boost multi_polygon

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, polygon, boost-geometry

There is a winapi function with the following prototype:

```
WINAPI CreatePolyPolygonRgn( POINT *pptl, INT  *pc, int cPoly, int iMode);
```

I can't realize the best way to convert multipolygon representation which is accepted by that procedure to the multi_polygon boost model. In case of interior-free polygon set the conversion to multi_polygon is evident.

But if we have interiors I don't see an easy way of conversion because we need to detect all interiors first and their correspondence to polygons. It's easy to collect all exterior and interior polygons as exterior polygons and put it to multi_polygon. But how to put then interior polygons represented as exterior to the corresponding polygon interior rings?